# Differences between direct-list-initialization and copy-list-initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, c++14, c++17

I would like to know if there is any difference the following two types of `std::vector` initialization in C++11 and later.

```
std::vector<int> v1 {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
std::vector<int> v2 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

Here is a complete code example that works fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v1 {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    std::vector<int> v2 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    std::cout << v1.size() << '\n';
    std::cout << v2.size() << '\n';
}
```

I see both initializations leading to identical results.

The example at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector uses the second kind, so that got me thinking if this kind of initialization has any advantage.

In general, I want to know if one initialization has a specific technical advantage over the other, or if one initialization is considered best-practice while the other is not, and if so why.

Especially, what I am concerned about is whether the copy-list-initialization has additional overhead due to temporary objects and copying?

Comment: The first one is called *direct-list-initialization*, the second one is called *copy-list-initializaiton*.  Those two things have exactly the same behaviour for `vector` hwoever

Comment: @M.M Is there a situation when *copy-list-initialization* may have a different behaviour than *direct-list-initialization*? Is there any copying involved in *copy-list-initialization* that can cause it to be slower?

Comment: @LoneLearner it depends which version of the standard is involved (some relevant changes in C++14 come into play here)

Comment: @Frank If the changes can be explained succinctly, can we have an answer that explains the difference between *direct-list-initialization* and *copy-list-initialization* in C++11, C++14, and C++17? If the answer is going to be too broad and verbose, then I would have to split this into three questions the appropriateness of which I don't know for sure.

Comment: It might be worth noticing that [different compilers](https://godbolt.org/) compile to the same code for the above example.

Comment: @Frank: "*it depends which version of the standard is involved (some relevant changes in C++14 come into play here)*" What changes? C++14 didn't change the behavior of copy-list or direct-list initialization. It changed the behavior of list-initialization in general, but those changes apply equally to both.

Comment: @NicolBolas I was just assuming that if the asker cared that much about the difference in behavior between the two, it would be safe to assume they would consider differences across standard versions to be relevant as well.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

List initialization is informally called "uniform initialization" because its meaning and behavior is intended to be the same *regardless* of how you invoke it.

Of course, C++ being C++, what is "intended" doesn't always happen.

There are basically three major differences between the behavior of direct-list-initialization and copy-list-initialization. The first is the one you will encounter most frequently: if list initialization would call a constructor marked `explicit`, then there is a compile error if the list-initialization form is copy-list-initialization.

This behavioral difference is defined in [[over.match.list]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.match.list):

> In copy-list-initialization, if an `explicit` constructor is chosen, the initialization is ill-formed.

That's a function of overload resolution.

The second major difference (new to C++17) is that, given an enum-type with a fixed underlying size, you can perform direct-list-initialization on it with a value of the underlying type. But you *cannot* perform copy-list-initialization from such a value. So `enumeration e{value};` works, but not `enumeration e = {value};`.

The third major difference (also new to C++17) relates to the behavior of braced-init-lists in `auto` deduction. Normally, `auto` behaves not too distinctly from template argument deduction. But unlike template argument deduction, `auto` can be initialized from a braced-init-list.

If you initialize an `auto` variable using direct-list-initialization with a single expression in the list, the compiler will deduce the variable to be of the type of the expression:

```
auto x{50.0f}; //x is a `float`.
```

Sounds reasonable. But if do the exact same thing with copy-list-initialization, it will *always* be deduced to an `initializer_list<T>`, where `T` is the type of the initializer:

```
auto x = {50.0f}; //x is an `initializer_list<float>`
```

So very, very uniform. ;)

Thankfully, if you use multiple initializers in the braced-init-list, direct-list-initialization for an `auto`-deduced variable will always give a compile error, while copy-list-initialization will just give a longer `initializer_list`. So auto-deduced direct-list-initialization will never give an `initializer_list`, while auto-deduced copy-list-initialization always will.

There are some minor differences that rarely affects the expected behavior of the initialization. These are cases where list-initialization from a single value will use copy or direct (non-list) initialization as appropriate to the list-initialization form. These cases are:

1. Initializing an aggregate from a single value which is the same type as the aggregate being initialized. This bypasses aggregate initialization.
2. Initializing a non-class, non-enumeration type from a single value.
3. Initializing a reference.

Not only do these not happen particularly frequently, they basically never really change the meaning of the code. Non-class types don't have explicit constructors, so the difference between copy and direct initialization is mostly academic. Same goes for references. And the aggregate case is really just about performing a copy/move from a given value.

Comment: This is a really nice answer. Just for completeness, would you care to add what is said in the comment, that `std::vector v {0, 1};` is a _direct-list-initialization_ and `std::vector v = {0, 1};` is a _copy-list-initialization_?

Comment: @YSC: The OP knows which is which. The question is what differences do they have.

Comment: This is not for OP, it's for future readers: if someone who doesn't know which is which get on this Q&A, I fear they won't get the max out of your good answer because they would missed that key info.

Comment: @YSC and Nicol, May I ask which initialization do you generally prefer while writing code? As a beginner to C++, learning good coding style is as much important to me as learning the concepts. I know a question like this comes with subjective opinion which is not a good fit for Stack Overflow. That's why I am asking you about this in the comments.

Comment: @LoneLearner: "*May I ask which initialization do you generally prefer while writing code?*" That is a matter of opinion, and SO tries not to deal in opinion-based questions.

Comment: Does SO prohibit discussing opinion about good coding style in comments too?

Comment: You missed http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#3.8, and a couple "(by copy-initialization for copy-list-initialization, or by direct-initialization for direct-list-initialization)" cases.

Answer (score 8):

I vastly prefer copy-list initialization in general (and particularly in the case of `std::vector`) because direct-list initialization is very similar at a glance to `std::vector`'s actual constructors when there is only one or two elements.

```
std::vector<int> x(2);
// is very different from
std::vector<int> x{2};
```

Being explicit about the fact that I'm assigning an initial value to the vector and not configuring it with the values is less prone to misreadings.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is relevant to the question

Comment: @Barry "or if one initialization is considered best-practice while the other is not, and if so why." Code readability/reviewability issues absolutely qualify under this part of the question.

Comment: Where "one" and "the other" are direct-list and copy-list initialization.

Comment: @Barry I just realized the title of the question has changed since I originally wrote this answer, so the wording definitely looks out of place now. I've cleaned it up a bit to better match the new question.